# Frame original size image

Tags: image, resize, frame

I have got question about frames.
Actually images in my site are automatically resized because of the frame (600x600).
How can i adjust frame to the original size of the picture ?
I'm adding example from my site.

[image]

I would like to automatically fit white lines like in the picture (orange lines are example) even if the picture is 250x250 or 900x900

Comment: Use CSS to scale it.  Use an converter to get the math to maintain the aspect ratio (if it's not a square).